# Chlorophyll supplements: metabolism of chlorophyll in the human body and proof for resulting health benefits?

Tags: nutrition, supplement, metabolism, biochemistry

I see people buy and consume powders that they claim consists of chlorophyll, calling it „lichtkraft“ in german, meaning „the power of light”. They are expecting health benefits from consuming it.

Did some research and you find a lot about the chemical properties of chlorophylls but not so much about how it’s metabolized in the human body and if there is any health benefit consuming it.

Are there any hints or even proof about how chlorophyll intake is metabolized and any resulting health benefits?

Comment: Such supplements may also contain magnesium and this [is important for the body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_in_biology), while most people do not meet the RDA for magnesium.

Comment: yes, but i get that from Mg supplements or even normal food as well ... ;-)

Comment: Worth noting that it's nonsense to claim "the power of light" for compounds which, after being consumed, will be metabolised entirely in darkness.

Answer (score 3):

According to [WebMD](https://www.webmd.com/vitamins/ai/ingredientmono-712/chlorophyll) (evidence from Natural Medicines Comprehensive Database), there seems to be lack of convincing evidence to claim that chlorophyll supplements help to treat pain, cancer, infections or other health conditions.

[Linus Pauling Institute](https://lpi.oregonstate.edu/mic/dietary-factors/phytochemicals/chlorophyll-chlorophyllin) provides few details about chlorophyll metabolism. They mention some old studies, according to which chlorophyll may promote wound healing. Most other studies have been done in vitro or in animals.

Many other "health articles" you find after searching for "chlorophyll health benefits" present chlorophyll in a misleading way and without references to studies, so it's best to skip them.

Comment: thanks for the sources ... on the Pauling page regarding wounds, it was topical application though.

Comment: Oh, yes, OK, you want to focus on oral supplements. It's even less evidence then.

Comment: Good answer - exactly the two references I had found :)